# Is it possible to add favorite tables in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working with 8 databases and lots of tables in each one of them.

It would be convenient for me to have a list of favorite tables and views that I can quickly access.

Does anyone know of such a feature or an idea how to achieve the same?

Thanks

Using the latest SQL Server 2014.

Comment: are all your databases on the same server?

Comment: what do you mean by access? do you meant to select top 100 rows ?

Comment: Using a schema might work for you...  Possibly...

Comment: Kamran, yes, of course..

Comment: TheGameiswar, I meant that I will see them in a list. So now when I click TABLES I see all the tables in the DB, but I would just want to see the favorites.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact thing called favorites that you are asking for. But you will find many add-ins that will be very helpful to you.

1. SQL Search:- You can type the name of the object, it quickly navigates to the object anywhere on the server.
2. SSMSBoost add-in:- I have not tried this myself, but heard good things about this.
3. Use Auto Hot Key:- This is my favorite. It is a keyboard macro program, You can create bunch of scripts and automate those scripts. For example:- I have keyboard shortcuts to connect to a particular database and then write

   Select * from my favoriteTable